# Gitlab rake backup timestamp to something else

Tags: linux, bash, backup, gitlab, scp

I want to create a bash script to be run in a daily cron tab.
Goal is to backup a tar file generated by gitlab backup from a server to another.

The filename will look like 1393513186_gitlab_backup.tar, where 1393513186 is a timestamp.

Everyday, a cron tab will check for the file, I need to retrieve the name from the latest in date.

I am not really used to bash script, I don't know how to parse all the filenames so I was wondering how could I achieve that ?

Is the timestamp really usefull or can i Just change it to a date in the ruby backup function ?
Will it affect the backup restore ?

My bash script look like this atm

```
    #!/bin/bash
    targetpath="/home/git/gitlab/tmp/backups"
    localpath="/media/backup/gitlab"
    today=`date +%Y%m%d`
    if [[ $localpath == "" ]]
    then
            echo "target path is not set"
            exit 1
    fi

    mkdir -p $localpath

    if [ -d $localpath ]
    then
            scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa username@192.168.1.146:$targetpath/1404135847_gitlab_backup.tar $localpath
    else
            echo "target path is incorrect"
            exit 1
    fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a custom bash script for transferring backups of file with versioning is a bit of a hazzle. Have you looked at the [backup](https://github.com/meskyanichi/backup) gem? It has tons of customization options and is well tested. Combine that with the [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem and you have all the features you are looking for and more.

We use this setup on our production system and we are really satisfied. A guide on setting it up can be found [here](http://www.icicletech.com/blog/gitlab-backup-made-easy)